# Find intersections with a table nested structure table in R

Tags: r, intersection

I want to find intersections between categories in my dataframe. For example, how many respondents from `region_1` took `category_n` and so on.

The problem is when I widen my long table it nests respondents' answers (which is logical). I tried to apply `unnest_longer` for each column sequentially but this solution does not fit to the desirable outcome.

What is the most effective and possible way to build the intersection table? Should I even widen it?

Data:

```
structure(list(resp_id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j"), category = list(c("c23745", "c58308", "c52057", 
"c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308"
), c("c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", 
"c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641"), c("c23745", "c58308", 
"c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", "c23745", 
"c58308"), c("c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", 
"c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641"), c("c23745", 
"c58308", "c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", 
"c23745", "c58308"), c("c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", 
"c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641"), 
    c("c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", 
    "c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308"), c("c52057", "c43641", 
    "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", 
    "c52057", "c43641"), c("c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", 
    "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308"
    ), c("c52057", "c43641", "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641", 
    "c23745", "c58308", "c52057", "c43641")), region = c("NY", 
"CA", "NY", "TR", "HU", "CA", "CA", "TA", "TD", "HR")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Desirable output:

```
     c4356   c1234

NY     23    ....

CA     ...   ....

TR

...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you, you're on the right track. A call to `unnest()` will put the data in a long tidy format. Then you can use `group_by()` and `count()` to find how many times each code is listed for each state. Finally, you can `pivot_wider()` to generate a table in the format you're looking for.

Here's an example:

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# I named your data `df`
df %>%
  unnest(category) %>%
  group_by(category, region) %>%
  count() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = category,
              values_from = n)
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood.

Comment: when I tried ```unnest``` on my original data, the error popped up ```Error: Incompatible lengths:```. this is because respondents picked different number of categories.

Comment: Are you able to share a minimal dataset that reproduces that error? The code I suggested works with the data you provided, and it's hard to debug without the data.